# servlet should wait for the task to finish

Tags: java, multithreading

How can I make the servlet to wait the current task to finish before it is destroyed?

Updated...

```
@WebListener
public class EmailServlet implements ServletContextListener {
private ScheduledExecutorService executorService;
ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture;
private int delay = 300000;
private int repeat = 300000;

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    System.out.println("The email servlet started");
    executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    scheduledFuture = executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Task3(), delay, repeat, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {

    scheduledFuture.cancel(true);
    executorService.shutdown();
    System.out.println("The email servlet stopped");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep checking the status your task using Future [isDone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#isDone%28%29) method. Once it returns true you can exit. Do something like:

```
while(!scheduledFuture.isDone()) {
  // wait to return till the end of this loop
}
```

But there is a risk here, if your task is never ending then you will never be able to return and servlet may timed out. So put the proper timed wait for the task to finish.

Comment: how to put the proper time wait?

Answer (score 0):

The classic way to "continue working" was simply to spawn a new thread:

> http://oreilly.com/catalog/jservlet/chapter/ch03.html
>
> Servlets can do more than simply persist between accesses. They can
>   also execute between accesses. Any thread started by a servlet can
>   continue executing even after the response has been sent. This ability
>   proves most useful for long-running tasks whose incremental results
>   should be made available to multiple clients. A background thread
>   started in init() performs continuous work while request-handling
>   threads display the current status with doGet(). It's a similar
>   technique to that used in animation applets, where one thread changes
>   the picture and another paints the display.

This was true long before "ScheduledExecutorService" existed.

Q: What is it you want to do that ScheduledExecutorService (or that a simple thread) doesn't already provide?

Comment: it will send emails in background of my application. I do not want to shutdown the server during sending of emails.